# Permutation of lists of list python

Tags: python, python-2.7, permutation

I want all the permutation and combinations of lists of lists that i have, i am using `itertools.product` to calculate the permutation but my computer hangs for indefinite time, What i might be doing wrong?

```
import itertools

#Lists of all the possible dimensions
upperchest_dim=range(32,52,1)
upperback_dim=range(32,52,1)
chest_dim=range(32,52,1)
waist_dim=range(32,52,1)
hip_dim=range(32,52,1)
bicep_dim=range(32,52,1)
elbow_dim=range(32,52,1)
thigh_dim=range(32,52,1)
knee_dim=range(32,52,1)
calf_dim=range(32,52,1)
height_dim=range(32,52,1)

#List of lists total
dimensions=[upperchest_dim,upperback_dim,chest_dim,waist_dim,hip_dim,bicep_dim,elbow_dim,thigh_dim,knee_dim,calf_dim,height_dim]

#Generate permutations of all the dimensions
print list(itertools.product(*dimensions))
```

The `list(itertools.product(*dimensions))` should have all the unique permutations possible for all the dimensions.

--
EDIT:
I think i am doing something wrong. I want a list of lists which has all the unique dimensions, for example [32,33,34,45,34,23,42,43,43,45,33] This is one dimension and the result should not contain this exact list again as this represents one body type.

Comment: Then Nest your `list(itertools.product(*dimensions))`

Comment: range(32, 52, 1) is 20 numbers. You got 11 of them. that means 20**11 combinations, which is approximately 2.*10**14. If you use int8 (which is possible i guess in this case), you use 1 byte per number. That means you need 2*10**5 Gb of ram to store it all. Something tells me you do not have that much. (This all in assuming i understand your question/code)

Comment: Ok, then i think i am doing something wrong. I want a list of lists which has all the unique dimensions, for example [32,33,34,45,34,23,42,43,43,45,33] This is one dimension and the result should not contain this list again. I think i will have 4400 such dimensions (20*11*20). Th

Comment: Can you show us a simple example and some expected results? I mean, we do not know if you want the permutations of the lists inside the list as well.

Comment: I don't want the permutations of the list inside the list. I want all new lists which has unique dimensions, as shown in comment above.

Comment: @rajat Then append that requirement to your question please.

Comment: I don't understand what is unique about  [32,33,34,45,34,23,42,43,43,45,33]. 33, 34, 43 and 45 each occur multiple times. Can you give an example with just three lists, and four choices or so?

Comment: I mean a unique list not a unique numbers, in the lists. These exact numbers should not appear in this exact sequence in any other list.

Comment: Then you're back to those 2 * 10**15 unique lists. 20 choices for the first number, 20 for the second, ... 20 for the eleventh, gives the number of unique choices I already gave in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That list would have 20 ** 11 = 2 ** 11 * 10 ** 11 = 204800000000000 elements. That's what's wrong.

Although itertools.product is an iterator that wouldn't hang indefinitely (it'd just take extremely long to iterate over all of it), turning it into a list() will hang until it has used all memory.

Answer (score 1):

No need for all this stuff, you can just use `permutations`:

```
from itertools import permutations

var = permutations([12, 34, 123, 12, 31, 231])

for perm in var:
    print perm
```

Even works with a `list` of lists:

```
from itertools import permutations

var = permutations([[1, 2, 3, 4], [24, 5, 12, 3], 123, 12, 31, 231])

for perm in var:
    print perm
```

Working [example](http://ideone.com/S1z5Ew).

If *for some reason* you want all possible permutations, even of permutations of the lists within the list, then, you will have to use the following code:

```
from itertools import permutations

var = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [24, 5, 12, 3], 123, 12, 31, 231]

# Getting all permutations of lists within the lists
output = []
for l in var:
    if isinstance(l, list):
        output += permutations(l)
    else:
        output.append(l)

perm = permutations(output)

for p in perm:
    print p
```

Working [example](http://ideone.com/XVarSC).

Answer (score 0):

If you on the last line do

`for d in itertools.product(*dimensions):
    print(d)`

it start to print

`...
(32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 37, 47, 45)
(32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 37, 47, 46)
(32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 37, 47, 47)
(32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 37, 47, 48)
...`

So "nothing" is wrong, the resulting list is so just enormously big that it can't be computed all once

Comment: This seems like it is giving the correct results. Although, it is giving all the permutations i want only the unique lists. For example: (32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 37, 47, 45), this should not repeat.

Comment: If you only want unique lists, use `combinations` instead. not that you will finish that calculation before the universe ends either :)